# What would happen if when falling down you get pushed up?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, collision, free-fall

I know it will be a weird question, but im not a physics well informed person and I had this unsolved question for long time.

What would happen if lets say you are falling with someone else from 10meters and in the last meter that other person pushes you up?, would you lose the falling speed or decrease it enough to survive the fall damage?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how hard you can push. Realistically, it would not have much effect. After all, the height at which you can throw a person is negligible compared to $10$ meters. Btw, at such heights, you can use the free fall equation and get the impact velocity of roughly $35$ km/h, so it is survivable as expected. My guess is that if the other person is trying to preserve you, his best strategy would be to hug you to cushion your fall. He can't change the impact velocity, but by lengthening the deceleration phase (which the most vital part) it might be worth it at his expense. Hope this helps.

Comment: It did, Thanks !

Comment: If the other person pushes you away (upward), then it's true that they can't change the velocity of your _combined_ center of mass, but by pushing you upward, and pushing themself downward, they increase their own final velocity while decreasing yours.

Comment: Yes but this effect is negligible at this height. Unless you’re pushing him with your feet, and you can jump several meters high with no momentum, it isn’t quite the same order of magnitude.

Comment: I was not trying to suggest that this technique could save the upper person's life. But, you said, "He can't change the impact velocity." I'm saying, that depends on which velocity you are talking about. If you are talking about the velocity of the combined center of mass of the two people, then you are right. One person pushing the other away won't change that. But if you are talking about the velocity of the individual people, then their velocities _can_ be changed (no comment on how "significant" the change) in equal and opposite directions (assuming they have the same mass.)

Comment: I actually meant that he can’t significantly change the impact velocity. Should have made it clearer